How to resolve "failed to create containerd task:failed to create shim task:Others("failed to receive.\"waiting for init ready\".BrokenChannel")error?
I'm trying to deploy a wasm app on a Kubernetes k3d cluster. Here's the command to create the cluster, label the node and create the runtime class:
k3d cluster create wasm --image ghcr.io/deislabs/containerd-wasm-shims/examples/k3d:v0.10.0 -p "8090:80@loadbalancer" --agents 2
sleep 2
kubectl label nodes k3d-wasm-agent-1 wasm="yes"
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: node.k8s.io/v1
kind: RuntimeClass
metadata:
    name: rc-spin
scheduling:
  nodeSelector:
    wasm: "yes"
handler: spin
EOF

Everything else is working fine. Wasm shims are registered, containerd is running, and the runtimeclass is also created successfully.
Here're the outputs for some of the commands that I'm executing:
containerd --config \
  /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/containerd/config.toml \
  config dump | grep spin

  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.spin]
    runtime_type = "io.containerd.spin.v2"
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.spin.options]

cat /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/containerd/config.toml
[plugins.cri.containerd.runtimes.spin]
  runtime_type = "io.containerd.spin.v2"

[plugins.cri.containerd.runtimes.slight]
  runtime_type = "io.containerd.slight.v1"

[plugins.cri.containerd.runtimes.wws]
  runtime_type = "io.containerd.wws.v1"

[plugins.cri.containerd.runtimes.lunatic]
  runtime_type = "io.containerd.lunatic.v1"

But when i'm trying to create the Pods, I'm getting the following error:
Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: Others("failed to receive. \"waiting for init ready\". BrokenChannel"): unknown

I don't know what's wrong at this point. My Pods are constantly in a CrashLoopBackoff state. Can someone please help me resolve this error?
